# Which scriptures ordain honor killing as the punishment for marrying someone from a different Varna?

Tags: caste-system, varnashrama

Is honor killing a Dharmic punishment for those who perform intercaste marriages?

Comment: Different varna or different kula?

Comment: Absolutely not.